# How to sort a list of lists by the first item of the sub-list then by the third item

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists. For example,

```
[ 
[1, 2, 0.10], 
[1, 3, 0.22],
[1, 4, 0.20],
[1, 5, 0.37],
[1, 8, 0.60],
[1, 10, 0.01],
[1, 15, 0.26],
[2, 3, 0.28],
[2, 6, 0.12],
[2, 7, 0.72],
[2, 10, 0.77],
[2, 11, 0.36],
...
]
```

I want to sort the list of lists by the first item of the sub-list then by the third item, and get top three result of each first item,
how to do that? thanks!

result example,

```
[ 
[1, 15, 0.26],
[1, 5, 0.37],
[1, 8, 0.60],
[2, 11, 0.36],
[2, 7, 0.72],
[2, 10, 0.77],
...
]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does "by third element of each first index" mean? In fact, what do you mean by "index" here? In your example output, it looks like it is sorted primarily by the first item of the sub-list then by the third item. Is that what you mean? It is also not clear what "top three result of each first index" means, and you show no example for that. Please edit your question for clarity.

Comment: @RoryDaulton thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution using `itertools.groupby`. We use a `tuple` key to sort by the first item and then the final item in reverse.

```
from itertools import groupby

sorter = sorted(A, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[2]))
grouper = groupby(sorter, key=lambda x: x[0])

res = [list(j)[:3] for _, j in grouper]

print(res)

[[[1, 8, 0.6], [1, 5, 0.37], [1, 15, 0.26]],
 [[2, 10, 0.77], [2, 7, 0.72], [2, 11, 0.36]]]
```

It seems you want to sort descending first, then ascending for the result. If this is a requirement, you can reverse the result, i.e.

```
res = [list(j)[:3][::-1] for _, j in grouper]
```

Thanks to @Ev.Kounis for the suggestion.

Comment: `res = [list(j)[:3][::-1] for _, j in grouper]` should also work.